# Instantiate object over network that doesn't appear on the player that created it

Tags: unity-game-engine, photon

a normal instantiate on a Photon network will create an object only in they client machine not on the network i want to achieve opposite of that, the object appear on all system except the player that created it.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could instantiate the object on the network and then use photons isMine function to destroy it on the client right after it spawned.

Comment: sounds interesting let me give it a try.

Comment: what exactly happened? did you just destroy it locally or with photonNetwork.destroy?

Comment: if you call destroy after ismine both are destroyed both local and network one.

Comment: thats unfortunate.. i guess some rpc calls that spawn them are the only way to archive this
EDIT: Maybe spawn an empty on the network, and then spawn the object if ismine is not true (on the empty)?!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of calling PhotonNetwork.Instantiate(), send RPC to other clients and instantiate non-network objects locally.

Or simply hide Photon-synchronized object as suggested in forum topic http://forum.photonengine.com/discussion/comment/24650/#Comment_24650

Do not use Unity Destroy() on objects created with PhotonNetwork.Instantiate().